Cursive in Lang’s “Algebra”

I was reading Serge Lang’s “Algebra”, the revised third edition. In p. 53, Lang introduces a concept of a category with a special cursive which I’ve never seen before. It is shown above. For me, it looks like some kind of alphabet ‘a’.
I first thought that it was \mathscr or \mathcal, but I couldn’t find such an alphabet in the $\LaTeX$ font table. Does anyone know what it is?

The names to look for are "Mathtime Pro 2 Curly Script" and "mtc". I don't know enough of Latex to tell whether mtc is a command in some package or if it's a font that you can select, thus changing the rendering of mathcal.

You can ask this on TEX site.

Looks like a fracture a; \mathfrak.

Relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470766/looking-for-a-curly-script-capital-a

Its a German capital A in Suetterlin, a Prussian invention of old German fracture script in 1911 for schools. The use was probably standard by ministries edict in Goettingen in 1920, when Emmy  Noether created modern algebra from scratch.
At those times classes of objects and maps were classified at the blackboard by fonts systems, script antiqua for numbers, gothic bold minuscles for vectors, capital antiqua for matrices, bold  and capital for 'large', complicated objects, double struck for multidimensional, Greek for indices and physical parameters.
The new abstract algebra used cursive capitals in order not to confuse students and as a signal, that classical algebraists would not understand anything.

[+1] for recalling this change of writing in Germany in the beginning of 20th century. Besides, why the previous downvote ? From somebody who doesn't understand the humor of the last sentence ?
